# Error: No more mocked responses for the query: mutation even though all args are accurate

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-testing-library

Still learning graphql but I've been fighting with this for a while. I've ensured my variables are coming in properly, and everything matches. But it's still returning an error. My queries and a delete mutation are working without issue, but this one isn't

```
    Error: No more mocked responses for the query: mutation UpdateTransaction($id: String!, $user_id: String, $description: String, $merchant_id: String, $debit: Boolean, $credit: Boolean, $amount: Float) {
      updateTransaction(id: $id, user_id: $user_id, description: $description, merchant_id: $merchant_id, debit: $debit, credit: $credit, amount: $amount) {
        id
      }
    }
    , variables: {"id":"619463389d0b3bb69eba7379","user_id":"61946c571c2a20c8f553d76b","description":"baking supplies","merchant_id":"walmart","debit":true,"credit":false,"amount":17.99}
```

Mocked response

```
    {
      request: {
        query: UpdateTransaction,
        variables: {
          id: testTransaction.id,
          user_id: '61946c571c2a20c8f553d76b',
          description: 'baking supplies',
          merchant_id: 'walmart',
          debit: true,
          credit: false,
          amount: 17.99
        }
      },
      result: jest.fn(() => {
        console.log('hello')
        return {
          data: {
            id: null,
          }
        }
      })
    }
```

even using a simple result: { data: { id: null } fails

mocked provider

```
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false} >
        <TxTable data={transactions} />
      </MockedProvider>
```

mutation gql

```
mutation UpdateTransaction (
  $id: String!,
  $user_id: String,
  $description: String,
  $merchant_id: String,
  $debit: Boolean,
  $credit: Boolean,
  $amount: Float
) {
    updateTransaction (
      id: $id,
      user_id: $user_id,
      description: $description,
      merchant_id: $merchant_id,
      debit: $debit,
      credit: $credit,
      amount: $amount,
    ) {
      id
    }
}
```

I feel like I might be missing something small.

Comment: Did you got any solution for it ?

Comment: Having this same issue. Any solution?